# getting rid of extra space in text switcher

Tags: android

I have an activity that extends ViewFactory. The activity does nothing more than act as documentation for my app, with 5 different 'views'.

Each view is placed inside a ScrollView in a TextSwitcher. The problem that I am facing is that if one of the five views has more text than the next view, there is empty scroll space.

Any ideas on how I can get rid of this space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TextSwitcher, as any ViewSwitcher/ViewAnimator will size to the largest child size by default.

This can be changed by setting the MeasureAllChildren property to false, e.g.:

```
TextSwitcher switcher = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
switcher.setMeasureAllChildren(false);
```

Then the size will be adjusted to the visible child on layout.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I am not sure how I missed that, luckily there are others out there that aren't as blind as me!