# ScrollView issue in android only on HTC mobile

Tags: android, scrollview

I am having the issue with **scrollview**. I have added the scrollview with text gallery.

It takes full window size, if text is less than window size. No scroll bar added. But when the text is greater than window size scroll bar is added. That's works fine. But some times only in HTC mobiles, it display scroll bar with half window size.

Can anyone please suggest what's i need to do?
I have added **fillViewport = true** property also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570311/recalculate-scrollview-on-different-viewflipper-views).